# TypeScript Compiler API: Unexpected behavior of getReturnTypeOfSignature() when return type is an array

Tags: api, typescript

Suppose the following component class with a public method `get_ids()` that returns an array of literal values (here: `number[]`):

```
class Component {
  private _ids: number[];
  public get_ids() {
    return this._ids;
  }
}
```

The following code works fine as long as the method returns anything else than an array:

```
const componentSymbol: ts.Symbol = checker.getSymbolAtLocation( componentNode.name ) // componentNode is the AST node of the component class
const componentType: ts.Type = checker.getDeclaredTypeOfSymbol( componentSymbol );

const property: ts.Symbol = componentType.getProperties[1]; // 2nd property represents the method 'get_ids()'
const methodDeclaration = property.getDeclarations()[0] as ts.MethodDeclaration;
const signature = checker.getSignatureFromDeclaration( methodDeclaration );
const returnType = checker.getReturnTypeOfSignature( signature );
```

However, since `get_ids()` returns an array, `returnType` equals:

```
{
  flags: 1,
  id: 4,
  intrinsicName: "unknown"
}
```

And there is basically no information that this should be an array of numbers.

Also, the return value of `checker.typeToString(checker.getTypeAtLocation(methodDeclaration))` is `() => any`. I would expect it to be `() => number[]`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where'd `signatureDeclaration` come from? It's not declared or assigned to. And you're calling `checker.getSignatureFromDeclaration( declarations[ 0 ] as ts.SignatureDeclaration );` without using its return type? The question should have an MVCE

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh: Thanks for your reply. I've updated the original post and I hope that it is a bit more prcise now.

Answer (score 1):

I have experimented a bit with the compiler options I have read in from the `tsconfig.json` file. Turns out that the `lib` option causes the problem. When commented out, I'm getting the expected result (`() => number`).

```
const compilerOptions = {
    allowJs: false,
    checkJs: false,
    diagnostics: false,
    inlineSourceMap: true,
    inlineSources: true,
    jsx: ts.JsxEmit.React,
    // lib: [
    //     // "es5",
    //     // "dom",
    //     // "scripthost",
    //     // "es2015.iterable"
    // ],
    module: ts.ModuleKind.AMD,
    noEmitHelpers: true,
    strictNullChecks: false,
    tripInternal: true,
    target: ts.ScriptTarget.ES5,
    downlevelIteration: true,
    baseUrl: "./",
    pretty: true,
    experimentalDecorators: true
};
```